# jQuery - does $(some_element) exist between $(this) and $(this).closest(container)?

Tags: jquery, dom

for example, given the DOM tree:

```
            form
             /\
         .tim   .steve
         /\           \
      .bob  .jobe      .jon
             /\          \
        .pim   .snort     .miles
```

I need a function for $('.snort') that will return 
    $('.tim')
if an element that matches '.tim' exists between $('.snort') and $('form'), otherwise return $(this).closest('form')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest` can do that by itself if you use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
var result = $('.snort').closest('.tim, form');
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and obvious! And I'm over here writing recursive $(this).parent() functions... *facepalm* Thanks. To show my appreciation, I've made you a node in the DOM tree!